# Is there a 3D format that supports instanced components?

Tags: 3d, 3d-modeling

I am looking for a 3D file format that supports instanced components/objects. That is, there is one geometry declaration and then it is instanced in numerous places. Open formats are very much preferred.

Comment: There is OpenFlight. (.flt)

Answer (score 2):

Collada (.dae) files seem to have support, according to 5-51 in the [1.4 specification](https://www.khronos.org/files/collada_spec_1_4.pdf):

> The `<instance_geometry>` element instantiates an object described by a `<geometry>` element.

Collada is supported by most platforms.